# Are there more transcendental numbers or irrational numbers that are not transcendental?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

This is not a question of counting (obviously), but more of a question of bigger vs. smaller infinities. I really don't know where to even start with this one whatsoever. Any help? Or is it unsolvable?

Comment: The algebraic numbers in $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) are countable. Because $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are uncountable, the complement of the algebraic numbers (the transcendentals) are also uncountable.

Comment: I've always been told there are more transcendentals than irrational non transcendentals, but I'd really like to see exactly why and how much.

Comment: I though the name "transcendental" means "prevailing", as there are more of them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The non-transcendental numbers (otherwise known as the **algebraic** numbers – [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number))  comprise a *countably infinite* set, whereas the transcendental numbers are *uncountably infinite*.

*(Why are there only countably many algebraic numbers? Because we can group them according to what polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ they are a root of, and any such polynomial has finitely many roots, and there are only countably many such polynomials.)*

The point is: in colloquial terms, there are more transcendental numbers than algebraic numbers.

Therefore, there are certainly more transcendental numbers than there are algebraic numbers that also are not rational.

Comment: It goes further. The set of **all computable numbers** is still only countably infinite, and that includes all algebraic numbers as well as familiar transcendental numbers like $\pi$ and e. (The vast majority of real numbers are uncomputable transcendentals. In fact, such transcendental numbers are the only reason the reals are uncountable in the first place, which is why people keep thinking they can prove the reals to be countable.)

Comment: ... and this is because any computable number must be computable by a Turing machine, and there are countably many Turing machines, which we know because you can write them down using countably many symbols from a finite alphabet.

Answer (score 14):

The set of algebraic numbers $\mathbb A$ is countable, so $\mathbb A\cap (\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)$ is also countable. On the other hand, the set of transcendental numbers $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb A$ must be uncountable, so $$|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb A|>|\mathbb A\cap(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)|.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the set of algebraic numbers is Countable.

For proving this, you can show that the polynomials with integer coefficients form a countable set, and that the set of their roots is also countable. The latter is just the Set of Algebraic Numbers (over $\mathbb{C}$). As the Algebraic Numbers over $\mathbb{R}$ form a subset of the former set, it must also be Countable.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the non-transcendental irrational numbers form a subset of $\Bbb A = \overline {\Bbb Q} \subset \Bbb C$, the set of complex algebraic numbers (i.e. the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$).

From a purely *set-theoretic* perspective, let us show that $\Bbb A$ is *countable*. For $a_0, \dots, a_n \in \Bbb Q$, let $R(a_0, \dots, a_n)$ be the set of the roots of the polynomial $a_0 + \dots + a_n x^n$ - a finite set with at most $n$ distinct elements. Note that since every element of $\Bbb A$ is the root of a such polynomial, then

$$\Bbb A = \bigcup \limits _{n \ge 1} \bigcup \limits _{(a_0, \dots, a_n) \in \Bbb Q ^{n+1}} R(a_0, \dots, a_n) .$$

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so will be $\Bbb Q ^{n+1} \space \forall n \ge 1$, so the inner union is a countable union of finite sets and therefore countable. Now, the outer union will be a countable union of countable sets, so again countable. The transcendental numbers will therefore be uncountable, therefore *much more*.

From a *measure-theoretic* point of view, countable sets are *null* sets for the Lebesgue measure, therefore again the set of the transcendental ones will be *much larger*.

Finally, from a *topological* point of view, it is slightly more technical to show that both types of numbers that you ask about are *dense* in $\Bbb C$, so from this point of view, they are *equally many*.

These statements remain true even when you consider only real algebraic and transcendental numbers.

Comment: I can't find a question on the site that asks how we know that all reals are either transcendental or algebraic. Is there one, or can you point me to a decent proof?

Comment: @MattGutting: Well, you need no proof, the definition says it all: you first define the algebraic numbers, and then you define the transcendental numbers as the *complementary* of the algebraic ones. This should answer your question.

Comment: Ah. Thanks! Somehow I overlooked that the definition of "transcendental" depended on the definition of "algebraic" that way. Silly me :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. All transcendental numbers are irrational.
2. The square root of 2 is irrational, but not transcendental.

Therefore, the set of irrational numbers is larger than the set of transcendental numbers -- in real numbers.

Comment: This is argumentation is false: "all natural numbers are rational, 1/2 is not natural - therefore the set of rationals is larger than the set of naturals" - but they both have the same cardinality. Taking away one element from an infinite set does not change its "size".